# Why am I able to start workflow on a document but not a document set?

Tags: 2013, document-set

I've created a document library and created a document set in the library.

However, after going through manage > add a workflow and adding from the "Collect Digital Signatures" workflow for the library I'm unable to start the workflow on document sets in that library.

I can start the workflow on individual documents, but not document sets.

Is there a way to run the workflow against the document set instead of each document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the "Collect Digital Signatures" will not work with document sets because it is designed to route specific file types for people to sign within those applications, not within SharePoint.

[From Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Collect-Signatures-workflows-90fcf6a9-4839-4138-a1fb-682d6d46a872):

> You can use a SharePoint Collect Signatures workflow to route documents created in Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, or Microsoft Infopath to one or more people for their signatures.

You can however use the Approval workflow with document sets.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to start workflows on Document Sets, however, you may need to configure specific Document Set actions to be able to do so. Further information available in this [Microsoft Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05#__toc355081428)

Comment: I'm confused here. From that article: "You can use the standard Review or Approval workflows with Document Sets". Also note that article applies to SP2010 and I'm on SP2013.

Comment: It seems to be generally best practice that you create a one-to-one relationship between content types and document sets, within those content types then, you can define the workflow settings. Something I don't believe you can do as a whole, for a document set in SP13.